# Selenium Wire Profile Setting

Tags: python, selenium

Cant specify the specified chrome profile in selenium wire. I ran the code and no error was found but the profile won't be specified.

Here's my code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    options = uc.ChromeOptions()
    options.user_data_dir = "C:\\Users\\Fadli\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data" # data dir
    options.add_argument('--profile-directory=Instagram_{}'.format(29)) # profile location
    options.add_argument('--no-first-run --no-service-autorun --password-store=basic')

    driver = uc.Chrome(
        options=options, 
        seleniumwire_options = {
        'proxy': {'http': '-',
        'https': '-'},
        },
        version_main=101)
```

Comment: what are the seleniumwire_options exactly? also if you tried this on a regular selenium instance and it worked chances are selenium wire does not support profiles

Comment: I'm not sure, but it's required to import proxy.  Yeah, It seems like the selenium wire doesn't support profile setting but I will look for another answer, thank you.